# How to check real App Store File Size, if the app is in test flight?

Tags: testflight, ios-app-signing

How to check real App Store File Size, if the app is in test flight?
app size in test flight is different, we have reduced the app size to 184 but in test flight it shows 197.
not able to understand why?
how to check the real app size?